# ECPM after migrating to new Admob

Tags: android, ios, admob

Admob is suggesting me to shift to the new Admob. I have my reservations and want to be fully prepared.

Has anybody shifted to the new Admob? Do you have any ads/sites/apps displaying ads (publisher) ?

What change did you see on your ecpm, income, impressions?

Any glitches? Problems? Issues?

Answer (score 1):

Shifted over about 12 months ago.

I have apps that are publishing ad space.

Income remained steady until I started using new features like dynamic mediation at which point revenue increased.

No problems.